# Axapta: Is it possible to move AOT nodes programatically?

Tags: axapta, aot

Is it possbile to move aotnode in axapta through code(I want to achive the same movement as done via alt-up, alt-down) 
Dynamics AX 2009 has AOTmove method, but when I try

```
#AOT
ProjectNode root;
//SysContextMenuAOT ctx = new SysContextMenuAOT();
ProjectGroupNode firstChild;
ProjectGroupNode secondChild;
;
//root=ctx.first();
root = infolog.projectRootNode().AOTfindChild("Private").AOTfindChild("TestProject");
root = root.getRunNode();

firstChild = root.AOTfirstChild();
secondChild = firstChild.AOTnextSibling();

secondChild = firstChild.AOTnextSibling();
secondChild.AOTMove(secondChild.AOTparent());
```

and then call it on whole project it successfully moves secondChildNode, BUT it deletes every subnode inside of secondChild.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what elements you are moving?
Also, take you code and make a job that is directly runnable and demonstrates your problem. Do it without reference to SysContexMenuAOT as it makes it (surprise) context dependent.

Comment: My bad. I though it was impossible to take project nodes but from context. Ok I fixed job. It runs on private project "TestProject"
with structrue like on http://imgur.com/Wk87n.jpg. 

I'm trying to move nodes inside of the project(http://imgur.com/rbwqd.jpg). If you run this job, it will move nodes, but remove subnodes(http://i.imgur.com/rxNCg.jpg)

Comment: The second `secondChild = firstChild.AOTnextSibling();` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to work (with project nodes).

`AOTmove` is used exclusively in form `SysFavoritesAddFavorite` and `SysFavoritesOrganizeFavorites`.
You may get some information looking there.